# What are the rules for a valid variable name in mirth?

Tags: mirth

I am trying to set up a transformer on a Database Reader to file writer channel. I am reading in a sql field called MRN which I would like to send to a variable called mrn. I added a step to a channel with a variable called tmp['MSH'] mapping to a variable called msg['MSH'] But mirth is giving me the error message:

*The variable name contains invalid characters. Please enter a new variable name*

What are the rules for a valid variable name in mirth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tmp` and `msg` are two built-in variables containing E4X mappings of the outbound template and inbound message, respectively. You would map, via a MessageBuilder step, from inbound to outbound with tmp['MSH'][...] = msg['MSH']...  where `...` refers to the appropriate sections. Essentially these are pre-populated javascript property arrays.

If you really want to create a variable for use in multiple places, the rules are alphanumeric plus '_', I believe.

In a MessageBuilder step, you could refer to a previously created variable with ${varname}.

I would recommend investing a little time in getting familiar with the basics. Documentation is wanting, to be sure, but [this blog post series](http://irwinj.blogspot.com/2008/12/getting-started-with-mirth-part-1_18.html?z) are a good place to start.

Comment: @dividius--thanks for all of your Mirth help. I was the tech writer for a Mirth system and then was put in charge of maintaining it. I've managed this far without delving into mapping but now one of mappings for one of the channels is not working so I'm learning fast!